# PaperTrail (paper_trail) error after upgrading to Ruby 2.1.2 with RVM. Uninitialized constant PaperTrail::Rails::Engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, paper-trail-gem

I am attempting to upgrade from `Ruby 1.9.3 to Ruby 2.1.2 (Rails 4.0)`. I am using RVM.

I installed Ruby 2.1.2, updated the Gemfile, including specifying `"gem 'paper_trail', '~> 3.0.5'"`, switched to Ruby 2.1.2 with RVM, created a new gemset, and switched to it.

I then did a bundle install.

> When I attempt to run rails server, I get the following error:
>
> /Users/sjohnson/my_app/config/initializers/paper_trail.rb:2:in `<top
>   (required)>': uninitialized constant PaperTrail::Rails::Engine
>   (NameError)   from
>   /Users/sjohnson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@rails4/gems/zeus-0.13.3/lib/zeus/load_tracking.rb:50:in`
>   load'    from
>   /Users/sjohnson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@rails4/gems/zeus-0.13.3/lib/zeus/load_tracking.rb:50:in
>   `load'    from
>   /Users/sjohnson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@rails4/gems/zeus-0.13.3/lib/zeus/load_tracking.rb:43:in`
>   load'    from
>   /Users/sjohnson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@rails4/gems/railties-4.0.5/lib/rails/engine.rb:609:in
>   `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'  from
>   /Users/sjohnson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@rails4/gems/railties-4.0.5/lib/rails/engine.rb:608:in`
>   each'    from
>   /Users/sjohnson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@rails4/gems/railties-4.0.5/lib/rails/engine.rb:608:in
>   `block in <class:Engine>'     from
>   /Users/sjohnson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@rails4/gems/railties-4.0.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in`
>   instance_exec'   from
>   /Users/sjohnson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@rails4/gems/railties-4.0.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in
>   `run'     from
>   /Users/sjohnson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@rails4/gems/railties-4.0.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in`
>   block in run_initializers'   from
>   /Users/sjohnson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:226:in
>   `block in tsort_each'     from
>   /Users/sjohnson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:348:in`
>   block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'   from
>   /Users/sjohnson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:418:in
>   `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component_from'  from
>   /Users/sjohnson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:427:in`
>   each_strongly_connected_component_from'  from
>   /Users/sjohnson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:417:in
>   `block in each_strongly_connected_component_from'     from
>   /Users/sjohnson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@rails4/gems/railties-4.0.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in`
>   each'    from
>   /Users/sjohnson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@rails4/gems/railties-4.0.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in
>   `tsort_each_child'    from
>   /Users/sjohnson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:411:in`
>   call'    from
>   /Users/sjohnson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:411:in
>   `each_strongly_connected_component_from'  from
>   /Users/sjohnson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:347:in`
>   block in each_strongly_connected_component'  from
>   /Users/sjohnson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in
>   `each'    from
>   /Users/sjohnson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in`
>   call'    from
>   /Users/sjohnson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in
>   `each_strongly_connected_component'   from
>   /Users/sjohnson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:224:in`
>   tsort_each'  from
>   /Users/sjohnson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:205:in
>   `tsort_each'  from
>   /Users/sjohnson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@rails4/gems/railties-4.0.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in`
>   run_initializers'    from
>   /Users/sjohnson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@rails4/gems/railties-4.0.5/lib/rails/application.rb:215:in
>   `initialize!'     from
>   /Users/sjohnson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@rails4/gems/railties-4.0.5/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in`method_missing'  from
>   /Users/sjohnson/my_app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
>     from /Users/sjohnson/my_app/spec/spec_helper.rb:10:in`require'     from
>   /Users/sjohnson/my_app/spec/spec_helper.rb:10:in `<top (required)>'
>     from
>   /Users/sjohnson/my_app/spec/api/v1/api_authentication_spec.rb:1:in`
>   require'     from
>   /Users/sjohnson/my_app/spec/api/v1/api_authentication_spec.rb:1:in
>   `<top (required)>'    from
>   /Users/sjohnson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@rails4/gems/rspec-core-3.0.3/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1057:in`
>   load'    from
>   /Users/sjohnson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@rails4/gems/rspec-core-3.0.3/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1057:in
>   `block in load_spec_files'    from
>   /Users/sjohnson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@rails4/gems/rspec-core-3.0.3/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1057:in`
>   each'    from
>   /Users/sjohnson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@rails4/gems/rspec-core-3.0.3/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1057:in
>   `load_spec_files'     from
>   /Users/sjohnson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@rails4/gems/rspec-core-3.0.3/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:97:in`
>   setup'   from
>   /Users/sjohnson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@rails4/gems/rspec-core-3.0.3/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:85:in
>   `run'     from
>   /Users/sjohnson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@rails4/gems/rspec-core-3.0.3/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:70:in`
>   run'     from
>   /Users/sjohnson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@rails4/gems/rspec-core-3.0.3/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:38:in
>   `invoke'  from
>   /Users/sjohnson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@rails4/gems/rspec-core-3.0.3/exe/rspec:4:in`
>   '    from
>   /Users/sjohnson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@rails4/bin/rspec:23:in `load'
>     from /Users/sjohnson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@rails4/bin/rspec:23:in`
>   '  from
>   /Users/sjohnson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@rails4/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in
>   `eval'    from
>   /Users/sjohnson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@rails4/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in`
>   '
>
> I attempted to run:
>       bundle exec rails generate paper_trail:install
>
> It indicated that the migration file already existed (PaperTrail was
>   working under 1.9.3). So, I ran it again:
>       bundle exec rails generate paper_trail:install -s
>
> It completed successfully, but I have the same issue.
>
> config/initializers/paper_trail.rb:
>
> ```
> # the following line is required for PaperTrail >= 3.0.3 with Rails
> PaperTrail::Rails::Engine.eager_load!
>
> module PaperTrail
>   class Version < ActiveRecord::Base
>     attr_accessible :captain
>   end
> end `
> ```

Ideas? Other information that would be helpful?

**Edit:**
Despite the reference to paper_trail 3.0.3 in the initializer file, the gem is at version 3.0.5 (as verified by doing a gem list). The references to 3.0.3 in the error trace are for Rspec.

Comment: They have updated paper_trail version to 3.0.5 and removed version 3.0.3 with this constant resolving.
I just did in my initializer

`module PaperTrail`
  `module Rails`
    `class Engine < ::Rails::Engine`
      `paths['app/models'] << 'lib/paper_trail/frameworks/active_record/models'`
    `end`
  `end`
`end`

Comment: I added the code to my initializer, and that appears to be working. If you enter this information as an answer, rather than a comment, I can accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just did in my initializer:

```
module PaperTrail  
  module Rails  
    class Engine < ::Rails::Engine 
      paths['app/models'] << 'lib/paper_trail/frameworks/active_record/models'  
    end 
  end 
end
```

And I recommend you to put this:

```
PaperTrail::Rails::Engine.eager_load!`
```

as the last string in initializer.

Comment: This answer worked for me as well on ruby-2.5.7, Rails 5 and paper_trail-12.1.0. It also works for ruby-2.7.2 and Rails 6. You can add your configuration for papertrail under `module PaperTrail`  but before `module Rails  `. e.g. `config.version_limit = 10`, etc.